# SignTool error while packaging Windows Store app

Tags: windows-store-apps, packaging, windows-store, signtool

During packaging the Windows Store application, I get an unspecified error [APPX1204]:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(1139,9): error APPX1204: Failed to sign 'D:\Projects\VS2012\Stroik\Stroik\AppPackages\Stroik_1.0.0.11_AnyCPU_Test\Stroik_1.0.0.11_AnyCPU.appx'. SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
```

Build output refers to the part of a file generated by VS2012:

```
<SignAppxPackage AppxPackageToSign="@(FinalAppxPackageItem)"
                 CertificateThumbprint="$(PackageCertificateThumbprint)"
                 CertificateFile="$(PackageCertificateKeyFile)"
                 HashUri="$(_HashUri)"
                 EnableSigningChecks="$(EnableSigningChecks)"
                 >
    <Output TaskParameter="ResolvedThumbprint" PropertyName="ResolvedThumbPrint"/>
    <Output TaskParameter="AppxPackagePublicKeyFile" PropertyName="AppxPackagePublicKeyFile" />
</SignAppxPackage>
```

Yesterday packaging proceeded successfully. Today I added aditional logic to my app and changed some data in manifest. Since then I'm reciving presented error. I tried to regenerate Certificate in Packaging menu, delete Store/Temporary Keys (then regenerate), ... much more but nothing helps.
Now I have no idea how to handle it. Furthermore packaging a new project (as it is provided by vs2012) results in the same error.

Have you got any suggestions how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted this is older - see if you can try it with a different live id
You could also try to generate a new app, and diff the manifests between the apps.

Now according to:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/f25939fb-c48c-4bd0-938e-6a0afbd2dca0/

you may want to sign out, use IE 'in safe private browsing' and create a new one.
Also ensure that IE is set in "Browsing History->Settings" to get a new version of the page every time.
Login with the new one and give it a try.

I'm not sure if this error is related here or not, but it's a starting point based on the prior feedback on the above post.

This japanese site lists the same error code and seems to have the same resolution as well

http://coelacanth.heteml.jp/blog/windows-8signtool-error-an-unexpected-internal-error-has-occurred/

Its worth a shot, but I'll admit on this one not being 100% sure, just trying to help out : )

Comment: This helped me, strange thing

Answer (score 2):

If it helps anyone else, I was trying to make the build on a network share (virtualizing windows). Creating it on the Windows partition solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was developing on a Virtual Machine in VirtualBox and tryed to publish to the shared folder.
Change the output folder to a local folder on the virtual maschine solved it.